# Reloading log4j.properties using Log4j Bridge

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I have to migrate an existing project from Log4j to Log4j2. The easiest way seems to use the [Log4j 1.2 Bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/index.html). This works fine, even the existing `log4j.properties` file can be used.

The question that I have is:

- Can the `log4j.properties` file be reloaded periodically at runtime, so that a restart of the application is not necessary after changing
  the `log4j.properties` file?

In Log4j version 1.x this could be done using
`PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(fileName, 10000)`,
but it seems this does not work any longer using the bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`log4j1.monitorInterval`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.apache.log4j.config.Log4j1Configuration.MONITOR_INTERVAL) system property:

```
log4j1.monitorInterval=10
```

The value is in seconds.

The above mentioned property can be set in any [property source](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties), e.g. in `log4j2.component.properties` file.